# BeautifulSoup метод .get

Tags: python

Подскажите что я делаю не так ?
данных нет и выходит ошибка по методу .get

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
from bs4.diagnose import lxml_trace

url1 = 'https://4lapy.ru/catalog/koshki/korm-koshki/sukhoy/'
HEAD = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEAD, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # item = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-common-item')
    item = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-common-item__info-center-block')

    catalog = []
    for items in item:
        catalog.append({
            'title': items.find('span', class_='b-common-item__image-wrap"').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': items.find('a', class_='b-common-item__description-wrap js-item- 
             link').get('href'),
})

    print(catalog)


def parse():
    html = get_html(url1)
    get_content(html.text)

parse()
```

```
C:\Users\Maks\PycharmProjects\Parcer_Python_Max\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Maks/PycharmProjects/Parcer_Python_Max/main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Maks/PycharmProjects/Parcer_Python_Max/main.py", line 47, in <module>
        parse()
      File "C:/Users/Maks/PycharmProjects/Parcer_Python_Max/main.py", line 44, in parse
        get_content(html.text)
      File "C:/Users/Maks/PycharmProjects/Parcer_Python_Max/main.py", line 33, in get_content
        'title': items.find('span', class_='b-common-item__image-wrap"').get_text(strip=True),
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Такая ошибка возникает когда вы пытаетесь вызвать метод у сущности `None`.

Вот список доступных

```py
>>> dir(None)
['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', 
'__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

`items.find()` у вас возвращает этот самый `None` и как видно из списка, метода `get_text` у него нет.

Решение: прежде чем использовать метод, убедитесь, что `items.find()` возвращает нужную вам сущность (объект)

Решение без привязки к `bs4`:

```py
match = items.find('span', class_='b-common-item__image-wrap"')
catalog.append({
            'title': match.get_text(strip=True) if match else None,
            'link': items.find('a', class_='b-common-item__description-wrap js-item- 
             link').get('href'),
})
```

Comment: немного по другому пошел. 
 items = soup.find('div', class_='b-common-wrapper b-common-wrapper--visible js-catalog-wrapper')
    for cat in items:
        title = cat.find('span', class_='span-strong').get_text()
        catalog.append([title])

    title = cat.find('span', class_='span-strong').get_text()
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
Здесь почему он ругается на метод find() ????

Comment: @Setborg вариантов много и это зависит от необходимых вам результатов. Главное, что вы понимаете, откуда ноги растут

Comment: почему он ругается на метод Find() ?

Comment: @Setborg это уже другая причина, не относится к данному вопросу. Если у вас возникает другой вопрос, то я вам рекомендую открыть новую тему с вопросом. Плюс, код в комментариях совсем не читабелен